# Java: Count ATC from a DNA sequence

Tags: java

I want to count the A, T and C from a DNA input in a textarea. 
I got this so far

```
String Seq = jTextArea1.getText();

int aCounter = 0;
for( int i=0; i<Seq.length(); i++ ) {
    if(Seq.charAt(i) == 'A' ) {
       aCounter++;
       System.out.println(aCounter);
```

Now I want to count the T and Cs too. I tried to copy this code for the T and C but it was not working.

Comment: Show your attempt (where you tried to copy some code for B and C)

Comment: @AlexShesterov It was the same code as above, I only changed the 'a's with 't's

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    String Seq = jTextArea1.getText();

    int aCounter = 0;
    int tCounter = 0;
    int cCounter = 0;
    for( int i=0; i<Seq.length(); i++ ) {
        if(Seq.charAt(i) == 'A' ) {
           aCounter++;}
        elseif(Seq.charAt(i) == 'T' ) {
           tCounter++;}
        elseif(Seq.charAt(i) == 'C' ) {
           cCounter++;}
    }
    System.out.println(aCounter);
    System.out.println(tCounter);
    System.out.println(cCounter);
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I mean, now I see I forgot the else if

Answer (score 4):

Don't copy code, understand and adapt it. Hint:

```
int aCounter = 0;
int tCounter = 0;
int cCounter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < Seq.length(); i++) {
  if (Seq.charAt(i) == 'A' ) {
    aCounter++;
  }
  // Put conditons here to recognize T and C.
  // Increment the counters.
}
```

Comment: I only duplicated my own code 3 times but it still not works

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use a for each loop: In my example it will go through each character of the string and check, whether it is contained as a key in the HashMap. If so, it will increment the value of the entry by 1.

```
HashMap matcher = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
matcher.put("A", 0);
matcher.put("T", 0);
matcher.put("C", 0);

for (Character c : seq.toCharArray()) {
    String key = String.valueOf(c);

    if (matcher.containsKey(key)) {
        Integer value = (Integer) matcher.get(key);
        matcher.replace(key, new Integer(value.intValue() + 1));
    }
}
```

This has an advantage, because if you'd like to extend your search for let's say 'G', in in the code sample from the other answer you have to add an entire code block like this:

```
int gCounter = 0;

elseif(Seq.charAt(i) == 'G' ) {
           gCounter++;}
```

In my code sample you simple have to add:

```
matcher.put("G", 0);
```

Hope that helps.